# Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `item`

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

This error shows in my dev tools when I load my app. I'm not sure how to go about changing it to fix the problem. I suspect it is a reason why when I deploy it to heroku it looks different that when I view it locally so I'm hoping if I fix this it will fix my problem with heroku as well.

Here is my code:

```
  return (
  <Container className="container" maxWidth="xl">
   
    <CssBaseline />
      {/* <Box sx={{ marginTop: 10, padding: 7, bgcolor: "#eeeeee", borderRadius: "0.3rem" }}> */}
        <Grid className="homeContainer" container spacing={1}>
          <Grid className="topGrid">
            <Grid className="imageContainer" item xs={4} sx={{ }}>
            <img className="cctLogoLarge" src={cctlogo1} alt="outline of horse with parliament buildings in background"></img>
            </Grid>
            <Grid className="introContainer" item xs={12}>
                <p>Welcome to Cap City Trotters! The CCT was created in 2019 by KMAC, Lynch, Bruster, and Damarts. Our Routes include several loops in both Ottawa and Gatineau.
                We are always looking for new members so if you want to join you can take a look at some of our main routes and signup if you like what you see!</p>
                {/* <a href="https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=97775&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/home&response_type=code&scope=read_all,activity:read_all">Test Connect to Strava</a> */}
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        
        <Grid >
          <Grid className="postList-grid">
            {/* {loggedIn && (
              <div className="col-12 mb-3">
                <PostForm />
              </div>
            )} */}
          <Grid item xs={6} sx={{ bgcolor: ""}} className="recentPosts">
              {loading ? (
                <div>Loading...</div>
              ) : (
                <PostList posts={posts}/>
              )}
          </Grid>
              {loggedIn && userData ? (
          <Grid>
              {/* <FriendList
              username={userData.me.username}
              friendCount={userData.me.friendCount}
              friends={userData.me.friends}
              /> */}
          </Grid>
            ) : null}
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      {/* </Box> */}
      </Grid>
  </Container>
)
```

I've looked at similar questions and answers but can't figure out how to solve this problem specifically.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks to me like you either use different library, or you're importing wrong component from it (default named), or have `item` prop somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error using the Grid2 component and I resolved it by removing the `item` from the Grid because the new version doesn't want the `item` prop.

You can check it in the docs https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid2/

Answer (score 0):

I have tested below mentioned 2 approaches in ReactJs and works fine.

If you work with **MUI Grid v2** (`import Grid from "@mui/system/Unstable_Grid";`)

then attach a **+** front of boolean value (+true)

```
<Grid item={+true} xs={12}>
  <Item>Submit</Item>
</Grid>
```

instead of applying

```
<Grid item={true} xs={12}>
  <Item>Submit</Item>
</Grid>
```

---

If you work with **MUI Grid** (`import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";`)

just normally set boolean values like below

```
<Grid item={true} xs={12}>
  <Item>Submit</Item>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you add a prop without a value to React component, it evaluates to `true`:

```
<MyComponent boo />
```

Here, `MyComponent`  receives a `boo = true` property. That's what you have in your code with `item`, while it shouldn't be a boolean value. Just pass some value to `item`:

```
<Grid item={somethingElse}>
```

Comment: Except the `item` property of `Grid` is a boolean property (https://mui.com/material-ui/api/grid/#props), so there's something else going on (possibly in code that wasn't included in the question text).